# Turned the television on or turned on the television?

Tags: grammar, word-order

I think turned the television on sounds better. I usually hear 'turned the television on' but I see 'turned on the television' in other references. Which is correct?

Comment: Technically neither. You switch something on or off if it has a button or a switch. You turn something on or off, open or close if it has a dial, wheel or lever. I'm just being pedantic as 'turn(ed) on' is now common vernacular and a personal preference.

Comment: Both work. Neither will confuse an audience.

Comment: Both are equally correct. Which is why both are commonly used in the first place.

Comment: But if te,evision is substituted by the pronoun "it", only "turn it on" is correct. "Turning on it" would have a very different meaning, i.e. attacking it when cornered.